# Blocking calls but do not block thread

Tags: c#, winforms

Recently I came across a proprietary third-party library and there is a method behave in this way:

```
public Point ClickOnDrawMat(DrawMat drwmat)  
{  
    Point pt;
    //waiting user mouse click on DrawMat and assign to pt  
    return pt;  
}
```

When my code calling this method from main thread, it will block on this method until user clicks, then get the point return from `ClickOnDrawMat`.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point userClickedPoint = ClickOnDrawMat(oDrwMat); //Wait until user clicked
    //Do stuff with point we got
}
```

However, it doesn't block the main thread.  I still can press other button/UI control while it is still waiting for user click.
I noticed that upon waiting for user click, one of the CPU core usage seems pretty high (~75%).

And this is an example of the call stack after I click on another button while it still waiting for user click:

```
myProgram.frmMain.button2_Click(xxx) Line 23
[External Code]
ThirdPartyLib.ClickOnDrawMat(xxx) Line 16
myProgram.frmMain.button1_Click(xxx) Line 14
```

I am wondering how can this be done?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Halcon, a proprietary library for computer vision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't tell you exactly how it is done unless somone had a copy of the library and they use a decomplier to see what the code is doing (if you want to do it yourself [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) is free and easy to use).

However by how you describe its behavior it is likely repeatedly calling [`Application.DoEvents()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) inside the function, this will let other messages be processed while the long running process is doing it's thing.

This is almost ***never*** a good coding practice for polling operations due to its high CPU cost, as you noticed, I recommend not doing it in your own code.

The "correct" way to handle this is use one of the [Asynchronous Programming Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx): the [async/await feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) added in .NET 4.5 or as a [NuGet package for 4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) ([TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx)), have the library raise an event of its own ([EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx)), or have the function use a callback function when it is finished ([APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx)). Inside the function itself it should use a event driven system internally so that it does not use CPU power while it is waiting for an event to happen instead of polling.

Comment: Because of what OP says about CPU activity, this answer sounds good.

Comment: Thanks! This explain the weird magic! Also thanks for the suggestion of dotPeek and Async/Await! May I ask, is there a way to use async/await feature in .NET 3.5?

Comment: No, but I added some more links that show some other options other than async/await.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the answer, it is resourceful. I will try to study more on your suggestion.